# Post migration - images do not display

Tags: images, migration

Here is migration quandry - going from one host to another. The blog domain name is unchanged.

- backed up the file system with everything to a .bz2
- backed up the SQL DB
- ftp'd the file system bz2 to the new host
- unpacked the file system with cPanel
- locations and permissions appear okay
- created db on new host with mysqladmin under cPanel
- imported the sql backup, seems okay
- adjusted wp-confg.cfg for db name. DB password is correct.

Now that the domain has moved the blog on the new host works perfectly EXCEPT pictures in the posts no longer display - just  box and the image file name.  The pics are where they should be in wp-content/uploads. The references in the post look correct but no joy when viewed.

As an experiment I inserted one of the pics into a new post. Same result. Further, in the media menu the picture also does not display but the names show as there.

Makes me nuts! Any help greatly appreciated.

The site is at http://www.thoughtpaths.com/

Comment: Do you have a different url?

Comment: Have you triple checked that the images exist on the new server?

Comment: This [image](http://thoughtpaths.com/wp-content/uploads/new-glasses.jpg) is returning a 404 page error. Can you download and view by some other means, like FTP?

Comment: Okay, I found the answer! And it ain't pretty.

Comment: Here it is. It is a function of the ownership of the upload dir when the bz2 was unpacked by cPanel. You can see the permissions but no the owner user number. the tar extraction must retain the original userid, which is not incorrect. Thus the dir is inaccessible.

Comment: How to fix it? Brute force :) Create a new uploads-temp, copy the files from uploads in there, then rename the uploadstemp to uploads. Voila! Fixed! My host had NO IDEA but the support are not linux guys. Anyway, ugly but it works. It should be added to any migrationg documentation as a possible gotcha.